# Where might virtual hosts be configured to use https?

Tags: ssl, https, virtualhost, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to setup a virtual host with https on a ubuntu server with a number of other virtual hosts.

None of the other virtual hosts make any explicit mention of ssl, and there are no specific host based references in the apache2.conf or httpd.conf.  However when i prefix their url's with ssl they load with no problem.

My virtual host has exactly the same declarations but when prefixed by https it does not work and instead the page just seems to hang or continually load.

How might these other hosts be configured to use ssl?

Thanks,

Comment: This is offtopic and belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me setup virtual hosts with https for my testing. Here is the article http://www.codealpha.net/631/name-based-virtual-hosts-with-ssl-using-apache2-on-ubuntu-lucid/